# How do I get the center of a circle in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying out [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) and I've made a few circles:

```
var circle = new Shape.Circle({
   center: [100,100],
   radius: 50,
   strokeColor: 'black',
   strokeWidth: 2
});
```

This draws a circle with center [100,100] (which could also be a point: `Point({x:100, y:100});`) and radius 50. This is great, this is a circle.

If I want to get the radius of a circle, I can do this:

```
circle.radius; // returns 50
```

But I don't know how to get the center back again. Part of the reason I guess is that `Shape.Circle` returns a `Shape` object, which does not have a `center` parameter ([documentation here](http://paperjs.org/reference/shape/)), but surely I can get this point back somehow. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since circles are centred on the position they're created at, you can get the position (as a Point) and the x and y values from that:

```
var circle = new Shape.Circle({
    center: [100,100],
    radius: 50,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2
});

console.log(circle.position.x, circle.position.y); //100 100
```

From http://paperjs.org/reference/shape/#position

Comment: This does it. `circle.position` returns a `Point` and it matches the original center closely. In my case, I get `{x: 29.99999999999997, y: 199.99999999999997}` instead of `{x: 30, y: 200}` because it looks like it's recalculating the center from the shape's border. But it's close enough for any practical purpose aside from like using `===`.

Answer (score 1):

While the `circle` object does not have a `center` property, if you read the docs properly you will find that it does have a `bounds` property.

In graphics, a "bound" is the rectangle that fully contains your object. So for a circle, the bounds will be a rectangle that touches the circle on the left, right, top and bottom. Therefore the center of the bound is the center of the circle (note: this is not always true for all objects depending on your definition of "center").

Paper.js will give you:

```
circle.bounds.x
circle.bounds.width
circle.bounds.y
circle.bounds.height
```

Therefore the center of the `circle` is:

```
var centerX = circle.bounds.x + circle.bounds.width/2;
var centerY = circle.bounds.y + circle.bounds.height/2;
```

Note: You will have to try this out yourself as I have zero experience with paper.js. I just read the docs

Comment: In addition to what you say, we can add that `circle.bounds` is a [Rectangle](http://paperjs.org/reference/rectangle/) and thus, have a readable [center](http://paperjs.org/reference/rectangle/#center) property. Using it removes the need to calculate center coordinates manually.

Answer (score -1):

Use :

```
circle.center[0] and circle.center[1]
```

cause its an array

```html
<script>

var circle = {
   center: [100,100],
   radius: 50,
   strokeColor: 'black',
   strokeWidth: 2
};

console.log(circle.center[0]);
</script>
```

Update: 
Sorry, I haven't read your question properly.
You can use circle.position to get the position of center.

Comment: He is saying that Shape.Circle does not have a `center` property. You're reading his question wrong